# Copy Transpose paste from 1 worksheet to another , matching sheet name

Tags: vba, excel, match, transpose

I have a sample of my sheet

A  1  2  3  4  5  6

B  2  3  7  8  9  5

C  4  2  7  9  5  0

I have created Sheets with name "A", "B", "C" (using VBA), howwever what I could not achieve is match Sheet name A to row A and copy Values (1,2,3,4,5,6), transpose it and paste it in sheet A. And i have a huge sheet so i am trying to loop my code so that it reads through A,B,C and so on. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
With ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address)
        .Range(.Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Address, .Range(cell.Address).End(xlToRight).Address).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet " & cell.Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=True
    Next
End With
```

Current sheet names to paste to will come out as "Sheet A", "Sheet B" etc If you need "A","B" etc then remove "Sheet " & from above

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this, but it throws an error at : Sheets(cell.Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Comment: It is reading my 1st column, copying successfully, but iguess its not able to match and paste it to sheet named "A"

Comment: Oh, I got it, It was my bad, i added a watcher and saw that it was getting empty value. Thanks a ton Sir, Your code works perfect.!

Comment: I take it you had blank rows in your data? If you need the blank rows you can change .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address to .Range("A100000").End(xlup).Address and add an if statement saying if cell.value <> "" then. If you could mark as answered that would be grand